# Закрывается burger меню при нажатии на любую часть экрана

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть burger меню, при нажатии на любую часть экрана закрывается, а хотелось бы, чтобы пока повторно не нажмешь на иконку burger меню не закроется.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $( '.menu-burger,.burger' ).click(function(event) {
    $( '.menu-burger,.burger,#top' ).toggleClass('active');
    $('body').toggleClass('lock');
});
})
```

```css
.burger{
  position:fixed;
  font-family:arial;
  width: 23.5vw;;
  height:100vh;
  background:#1f1f1f;
  color:#F8EAD6;
  left:-200%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index:40;
  margin-top:4.166666666666667vw;
}

.burger p {
    text-align: center;
    color:#F8EAD6;
    font-family:arial black;
    margin-bottom:2.604166666666667vw;
    align-self:center;
    font-size: 1.875vw;
    margin-top:1.40625vw;
}

.burger li a{
  color:#F8EAD6;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#burger-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}

.main-menu{
    height:4.166666666666667vw;
  display:flex;
  align-self: flex-start;
  z-index:2;
}

.main-menu ul{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.main-menu li{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  padding-left:1.09375vw;
  padding-right:2.60416666667vw;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-menu a{
  width:15.625vw;
  margin-bottom: 1vw;
  padding: 0.2604166666666667vw 0;
  padding-left: 1.510416666666667vw;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F8EAD6;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.menu-burger{
  cursor:pointer;
  display:flex;
  position:absolute;
  width:30px;
  height:20px;
}

.menu-burger span{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#fff;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:5px;
  top:6.5px;
  border-radius:2px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0.1s;
}

.menu-burger:before,
.menu-burger:after{
  content:"";
  background-color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:5px;
  left:0;
  border-radius:2px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.1s;
}

.menu-burger:before{
  top: -1px;
}

.menu-burger:after{
  bottom:0;
}

.menu-burger.active:before{
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  top:8px;
}

.menu-burger.active:after{
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  bottom:7px;
}

.menu-burger.active span{
  transform:scale(0);
}

.burger.active {
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="burger-top" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
        <div class="menu-burger">
        <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>

<div class="burger">
<p>Меню</p>
<!--Не обращайте внимание сюда
  /* <div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" id="burger-container">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="m-menu">
    <div class="row" id="m-search">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <?php echo $search; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div> 
    </div>  -->
    <div class="main-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="https://impulse-comp.kz/">Главная</a>
        <a href="">Каталог</a>
        <a href="">Конструктор</a>
        <a href="">Прокачка</a>
        <a href="">Блог</a>
        <a href="">О нас</a>
        <a href="" style="border:0;">Контакты</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь contains.

Т.к. приложенный вами код нельзя выполнить, сделаю для демонстрации с другой разметкой.

```js
const wraper = document.querySelector(".burger-wrap");

document.querySelector(".burger__btn").addEventListener("click", (e) =>
{
  wraper.classList.toggle("burger--open");
});

// добавляем обработчик кликов по всему документу (странице)
document.addEventListener("click", (e) =>
{
  // проверяем, что элемент на который кликнули (e.target) не находится в блоке .burger-wrap
  if (!wraper.contains(e.target))
  {
    wraper.classList.remove("burger--open"); // 
  }
});
```

```css
.burger-wrap > .burger-content
{
  display: none;
}
.burger-wrap.burger--open
{
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #787878;
}
.burger-wrap.burger--open > .burger-content
{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="burger-wrap">
   <button class="burger__btn">Button</button>
   
   <div class="burger-content">
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
      <li>Пункт 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

UPD: И действительно, как подсказали в комментариях, я не правильно прочитал вопрос.
Если я правильно вас понимаю, то закрывается по клику по области вокруг пунктов, а не в целом за фоном меню (судя из версии, что на вашем сайте).
Чтобы избежать этого, я думаю стоит убрать из:

```js
  $( '.menu-burger,.burger').click(...);
```

`.burger`:

```js
  $( '.menu-burger').click(...);
```

Comment: Ваш код работает ровно так как не хочет автор :) меню закрывается при клике в пустую область :) автор хочет чтобы оно закрывалось при клике только по кнопке(перечитайте вопрос), обработчик клика по любому элементу лишний :)

Comment: Кхм) Как я так умудрился прочитать) Но все равно, его код не должен закрывать по любой области, хотя если он про область самого меню (вокруг кнопок). Судя из того, что на сайте - именно это ему и мешает.

Comment: В вашем случае закрывается по клику в любом месте кроме меню, что мешает автору вопроса гадать не буду, это надо выяснять у автора, я читаю дословно что там написано и там именно про клик в любую область кроме кнопки :)

Comment: Обновил) Думаю я правильно понял)

Comment: Здравствуйте, да я попробовал как вы описали в UPD и вправду все заработало)
Прошу прощения, что только увидел ответ. Еще раз благодарю за помощь)